# Capturar los errores desde el back

Tags: angular, spring-boot

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podrar ver en esta captura de pantalla no logro capturar los mensajes de error que vienen desde el backend. en la console di undefined el Backend lo estoy haciendo con spring-boot. les agradezco su ayuda

metodo create para crear un nuevo diplome

```
  public create(diplome: Diplome): Observable<Diplome> {
    return this.Http.post(this.url, diplome, { headers: this.httpHeaders }).pipe(
      map((response: any) => response.diplome as Diplome),
      catchError(e => {
        console.error(e.error.message);
        swal.fire("Erreur au moment de la création", e.error.message, 'error');
        return throwError(e)
      })
    );
  }
```

metodo de Postmapping Spring-boot

```
 @PostMapping("/diplomes")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody Diplome diplome, BindingResult result) {
        Diplome newDiplome = null;
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            List<String> errors = result.getFieldErrors().stream()
                    .map(err -> "Le champ '" + err.getField() + "' " + err.getDefaultMessage())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
 
            response.put("errors", errors);
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
 
        try {
            newDiplome = iDiplomeService.save(diplome);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            response.put("message", "Erreur au moment de la création d'une diplome dans la base de données");
            response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": ".concat(e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage())));
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        response.put("message", "Le Diplome a été créer avec satisfaction");
        response.put("diplome", newDiplome);
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: En vez de hacer `console.error(e.error.message);` imprime el objeto `e`, es decir `console.error(e);` Y comenta que obtienes

Comment: ok gracias por tu respuesta te informare  si todo sale bien